# error after importing progect from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting this error in Android Studio after i've imported a project from eclipse

> C:\Users\admn.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\9642e2c79c11b0f8f68064f6cbc64e8e\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(5, 5) error: resource previously defined here.
>
> C:\Users\admn.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.2.0.aar\65648038dd839bb6dcf32985b0a61b7d\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(203, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/background' with config ''.
>   Error:(203, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMajor' with config ''.
>
> Error:(203, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMinor' with config ''.
>
> Error:(203, 5) error: resource previously defined here.
>
> Error:(203, 5) error: resource previously defined here.
>
> D:\pc\andoid-app\apps\infoapps\coloring by number\Coloring Book\studiocoloring\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(165) duplicate value for resource 'attr/background' with config ''.
>
> Error:(12) resource previously defined here.
>
> Error:(190) resource previously defined here.
>
> Error:(357) duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMajor' with config ''.
>
> Error:(357) duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMinor' with config ''.
>
> Error:(190) resource previously defined here.
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>
> com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

**build.geadl module:app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

**build.gradl project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.namer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.name.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.name.PicSelect"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.name.PicItem"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.name.FloodFillActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Post the content of the D:\pc\andoid-app\apps\infoapps\coloring by number\Coloring Book\studiocoloring\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml file.

Comment: thnx izaela
values.xml [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r3J8pHVWTzgndKG7mcTBE3DCfGHzBnot/view?usp=sharing)